# Triangularisation of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I understand that Upper triangular matrices must have at least one eigenvector, but why does this mean that the basis of $[T]_B$ must contain an eigenvector for $[T]_B$ to be upper triangular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B=(v_1,v_2,\dots)$ is such that $[T]_B$ is triangular, then $v_1$ is an eigenvector. This follows from the definition of the matrix $[T]_B$.